# mypy: Dict containing instances of different subclasses

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, typing, mypy

In the following code example we have a dict with contains an instance of an abstract base class and an instance of its sub-type.

```py
from typing import Dict, Union


class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0


class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.y = 1


d: Dict[str, Base] = {
    'base': Base(),
    'sub': Sub()
}

print(d['sub'].y)
```

Accessing an instance variable of sub-type leads to the linter warning `Unresolved attribute reference 'y' for class 'Base'` in Pycharm.

Checking this example with mypy raises an error:

```
error: Item "Base" of "Union[Base, Sub]" has no attribute "y"
```

Changing the code to

```py
d: Dict[str, Union[Base, Sub]] = {
    'base': Base(),
    'sub': Sub()
}
```

fixes the linter warning in Pycharm, but the error is still raised in mypy.

From the [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#invariance-vs-covariance) I know that "most mutable generic collections are invariant". I therefore suppose the `dict` is "invariant"?

Does this mean it is not possible to have an dict with instances of different subclasses in mypy? If so, can this code somehow be changed so it passes mypy?

As the keys are not known prior to runtime, I assume `TypedDict` is not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cast` to tell `mypy` that yes, you promise that `d['sub']` will be an instance of `Sub` (not just an unspecified subclass of `Base`), which will have a `y` attribute.

```
print(typing.cast(Sub, d['sub']).y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a field from value when its type can be the one without that field (`Base` in your case) -- it's an error from `mypy`s perspective (and from mine too).

You should be either rethink your classes and inheritance hierarchy or add `isinstance` checks like

```py
... # same as before
value = d['sub']
if isinstance(value, Sub):
    print(value.y)
```

and `mypy` will tell something like

```sh
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it is not possible to accept two answers. I accepted the other one, because in my case I can guarantee the that  `d['sub']` has the type `Sub` and the check `isinstance(value, Sub)` would be unnecessary.